# Flash AS3 AIR on iOS not streaming HLS AAC

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, aac

This is already a nightmare for me..
I have to get this AAC working for a project and there is no other way and no alternatives..

I'm using this library https://github.com/mangui/flashls and successfully stream ACC and MP3 with M3U8.

Now I have to get it working in iOS and in iOS, there is only the MP3 stream working. AAC seems to work, as the buffer is loading etc, but there is no audio.

The AIR has H.264/AAC Playback Support for iOS since AIR 2.
Source: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/flashplayer-air-feature-list.html

And there are some NetStream members that are not supported, that might be the cause why audio is not playing in iOS. 
Source: "Support for H.264 encoded video in AIR for iOS" http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html

Also the guy who wrote FlashHLS responded that he does not find any problem with the log files here: https://github.com/mangui/flashls/issues/150

NOTE: I'm streaming only audio and I only need audio. Would be great if there is a audio only library that does not use stageVideo.

Here is all my testing app code:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/y1t9jkv7tg1lgvy/iOS%20test%20ACC.zip?dl=0

The AAC stream: http://media.err.ee/viker/mp4:2104941.m4a/playlist.m3u8

Thank you!!

Comment: What is this language you people are speaking in Japan, huh?? Just joking man. So just for an alternative test: You can try to load one of your AAC files into this **[AAC to FLV](http://www.swfcabin.com/swf-files/1411416171.swf)** tool I did a while back. After a **Play** test just click **Export FLV**. Now if that flv can also be played via `netStream` within your app on iOS then _maybe_ I can help you... I'm not sure if this iOS has problem with FLVs or with using `Appendbytes` in code to make FLVs, no iPhone to confirm.

Comment: try this **[AAC file](http://media.err.ee/viker/mp4:2104941.m4a/media_w1707182057_12.aac)** just use right-click & save. It's from playlist.m3u8 results.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Nope, the converted FLV did not play audio on both Android or iOS devices. this is the code I tired http://jsfiddle.net/fch1a8t0/

Comment: @TarmoSaluste Have you tried using a `HTML5` `<audio>` element included in html page showed in your app using a `StageWebView` element ?

Comment: @akmozo no I have not, this seems a bit too extreme hack-around and the control over seeking, pausing would be difficult. Also the app should be lightweight. I will look into this in the last resort. Or if you have a example script I can try

Comment: @TarmoSaluste I know man, It was just to test your stream, may be it has a problem.

Comment: @akmozo ah, I see now what you mean. Good idea! I give it a try and see if I can play the stream in any other way on iOS to see if the stream is good

Comment: @akmozo the stream still seems to play in iOS, so there can't be problem with that. I suspect that there is some problems with NetStream in iOS, still..

Comment: I think iOS is hard-coded not to like FLV. Even if those FLVs had played I found out the `appendBytes` method is not supported so wouldnt be able to use that trick to play AAC.. Is there anyway to get sent as M4A files instead of AAC? (server setup options?)

Comment: Yes, I have heard also that the Apple were hating Flash for some time. I would not be amazed if Apple jerks did write some code to mess with the FLV. But I am streaming M4A files already. They are AAC encoded.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I was just checking now, and the Chunklist consists of .aac files. I will see if I can get to ghange them to m4a, if that is possible

Comment: @akmozo nope, it cannot be changed :(